# Convert m3u8 playlist files to XML list

Tags: php, xml, terminal, m3u8

I was wondering if there is any way to convert an `M3U8` playlist to `XML` using Linux shell or PHP? For example.

M3U8 Playlist file

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="Canal 26" tvg-logo="https://demo.com/xDjOUuz.png" group-title="Argentina",
https://demolivevideo1.com/playlist.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="LN"  tvg-logo="https://demo2.com/vJYzGt1.png" group-title="Argentina",
https://demolivevideo2.com/playlist.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="ABC" tvg-logo="https://demo3.com/5CVl5EF.png" group-title="Australia",
https://demolivevideo3.com/playlist.m3u8
```

XML File structure after conversion.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <channels>
    <name>Canal 26</name>
    <banner>https://demo.com/xDjOUuz.png</banner>
    <url>https://demolivevideo1.com/playlist.m3u8</url>
    <country>Australia</country>
  </channels>
  <channels>
    <name>LN</name>
    <banner>https://demo.com/xDjOUuz.png</banner>
    <url>https://demolivevideo2.com/playlist.m3u8</url>
    <country>Australia</country>
  </channels>
  <channels>
    <name>ABC</name>
    <banner>https://demo.com/xDjOUuz.png</banner>
    <url>https://demolivevideo3.com/playlist.m3u8</url>
    <country>Australia</country>
  </channels>
</data>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit (a lot, actually) of a hack (a few string replacements and splitting), but it should get you there, or close enough (in PHP):

```
$m3u = '[your playlist above]
';            

$newFile = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data></data>
';   

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($newFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$destination = $xpath->query('/data');

#some of the steps next can be combined, but I left them separate for readability
$step1 = explode('#EXTINF:-1 ',str_replace('#EXTM3U','',$m3u));
$step2 = array_slice($step1,1);

foreach ($step2 as $item) {
    $step3 = str_replace('" ','" xxx',explode(',', $item));
    $step4 = explode('xxx',$step3[0]);
    $link = explode(',',$item)[1];
    $params = [];
    foreach ($step4 as $step)
       {
       $param = explode('=',$step)[1];
       array_push($params,$param);
       }

    #create you <channels> template
    $chan = "
    <channels>
    <name>{$params[0]}</name>
    <banner>{$params[1]}</banner>
    <url>{$link}</url>
    <country>{$params[2]}</country>  
    </channels>";

    $template = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $template->appendXML($chan);
    $destination[0]->appendChild($template);
       
};

echo $doc->saveXml();
```

And that should be your expected output.

Comment: I tried the PHP codes but I'm not getting an XML format on the ouput.

Comment: This is what I get on the echo output when I check the source 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data/>`

Comment: @robotron  Not sure why you have that problem; [take a look here.](https://3v4l.org/H6O7p)

Comment: Yes, it does work fine I was making a mistake. Thanks,  I noticed when reading this file  [link](https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/categories/business.m3u)
 that the URL comes with extra characters, how can I prevent that from showing on the `<URL></URL>`?